# Rails 4, add checkbox for each object in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, loops, checkbox, html-table

I want to conditionally add a check box to each object in a table, such that, a user can select multiple items. When the user click's submit - I want to change the state of the objects that were selected and update the table via ajax. I've looked at 
`collection_check_boxes` but I'm not sure how I can implement it in this situation.

See below, the code I wish to modify - to include the check boxes on each line.

```
<% if @events != nil %>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= event.driver.name%></td>
        <td><%= event.name%></td>
        <td><%= event.drop_off? ? "Drop Off At" : "Pick Up From" %></td>
        <td><%= event.location_name%></td>
        <td><%= event.is_game ? "Game" : "Not Game(event, practice)" %></td>
        <td><%= event.location_address %></td>
        <td><%= event.date ? event.date.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") : "Please Enter Details on TeamSnap!"%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

This is what I came up with:

```
<% if @events != nil %>
    <%= form_tag events_swap_path(@carpool) do %>
        <div><%= submit_tag 'Swap!' %></div>
        <% @events.each do |event| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= event.driver.name%></td>
            <td><%= event.name%></td>
            <td><%= event.drop_off? ? "Drop Off At" : "Pick Up From" %></td>
            <td><%= event.location_name%></td>
            <td><%= event.is_game ? "Game" : "Not Game(event, practice)" %></td>
            <td><%= event.location_address %></td>
            <td><%= event.date ? event.date.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") : "Please Enter Details on TeamSnap!"%></td>
            <td><%= fields_for "events[]", event do |f| %>
                        <%= f.check_box :id, {multiple: true}, 1, nil %>
                    <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, when I submit I am getting an undesirable hash structure in the params hash for the events I selected. See what is being placed in params hash after submit below:

```
{"commit"=>"Swap!", "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P0JNhyco3B5ijMFurf3SIQ9ILTT9CGUyrmdInoshwPWvyF+E/xoWbEKH7ubN30EwIOjKQw1rwC3Vv8ZCgaMoKQ==", "events"=>{"869"=>{"id"=>["1"]}, "870"=>{"id"=>["1"]}}, "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"swap", "carpool_id"=>"8"}
```

Ideally I would be getting something like.

`events => {"id"=>"869", "id"=>"870"}`

So I could easily iterate through the selected list of events and extract all event id's.

Comment: Look's like write code for me. Please show what have you tried so far. Stackoverflow is not a write-code-for-me resource.

Comment: Understood,  working on it, it's a bit of a mess at the moment. will update shortly.

Comment: Updated with a solution that is very close...maybe you can have a look

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. See the solution I posted if you are at all interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
<% if @events != nil %>
    <%= form_tag events_swap_path(@carpool) do %>
        <div><%= submit_tag 'Swap!' %></div>
        <% @events.each do |event| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= event.driver.name%></td>
            <td><%= event.name%></td>
            <td><%= event.drop_off? ? "Drop Off At" : "Pick Up From" %></td>
            <td><%= event.location_name%></td>
            <td><%= event.is_game ? "Game" : "Not Game(event, practice)" %></td>
            <td><%= event.location_address %></td>
            <td><%= event.date ? event.date.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p") : "Please Enter Details on TeamSnap!"%></td>
            <td>
                    <%= check_box_tag 'event_ids[]', event.id %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

params hash upon submit:

```
{"commit"=>"Swap!", "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UrVdb0+iCUWYSGdmRpbMTp4Ax+/VkN55eCAsz6maHRDCP09sl5DDN7hDSO4mtF9fsaAgmCXze2YD+KIToxj1zA==", "event_ids"=>["869", "870"], "controller"=>"events", "action"=>"swap", "carpool_id"=>"8"}
(byebug)
```